# How do we connect to Active Directory Server using Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I have never work with Active directory server I need some help that how should I connect to Active Directory by using Java. What would be the best approach to deal with AD with Java. Any Java API is there for that.

Comment: Have you tried at least search the answer in some web search ?

Comment: Yes I have tried and read some article about LDAP and JNDI to conned with active directory using java.

Comment: So you discovered that JNDI is a Java API that is 'there for that'. So what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

What you should know before start the work with Active Directory is:

[LDAP - Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)

[JNDI - Java Naming and Directory Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html)

You should use some tutorial first, and then having some real problem, try to ask about it.

Some tutorials:

- [JNDI - Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/TOC.html)
- [LDAP & JNDI](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-0324-ldap.html)

The description of whole cooperability with AD will took lot of time, and the best approach is always open discussion about what best is.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring-LDAP](http://www.springsource.org/ldap)

Comment: LDAP + JNDI is too hard to use. spring-ldap is a good choice.